Actix Web middleware to limit endpoint requests
I would like to publish my first package to crates.io - it is a simple library crate that allows one to rate limit server endpoints.
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use chrono::{DateTime, Duration, Utc};
use actix_service::{Service, Transform};
use actix_web::dev::{ServiceRequest, ServiceResponse};
use actix_web::{Error, HttpResponse};
use futures::future::{ok, Ready};
use std::task::{Context, Poll};
use actix_web::body::{BoxBody, EitherBody, MessageBody};


pub struct Limiter {
    pub ip_addresses: HashMap<String, (DateTime<Utc>, usize)>,
    pub duration: Duration,
    pub num_requests: usize,
}

pub struct LimiterBuilder {
    duration: Duration,
    num_requests: usize,
}

impl LimiterBuilder {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            duration: Duration::days(1),
            num_requests: 1,
        }
    }

    pub fn with_duration(mut self, duration: Duration) -> Self {
        self.duration = duration;
        self
    }

    pub fn with_num_requests(mut self, num_requests: usize) -> Self {
        self.num_requests = num_requests;
        self
    }

    pub fn build(self) -> Arc<Mutex<Limiter>> {
        let ip_addresses = HashMap::new();

        Arc::new(Mutex::new(Limiter {
            ip_addresses,
            duration: self.duration,
            num_requests: self.num_requests,
        }))
    }
}

pub struct RateLimiter {
    pub(crate) limiter: Arc<Mutex<Limiter>>,
}

impl RateLimiter {
    pub fn new(limiter: Arc<Mutex<Limiter>>) -> Self {
        Self { limiter }
    }
}

pub struct RateLimiterMiddleware<S> {
    pub(crate) service: Arc<S>,
    pub(crate) limiter: Arc<Mutex<Limiter>>,
}

impl<S, B> Transform<S, ServiceRequest> for RateLimiter
where
    S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response=ServiceResponse<B>, Error=Error> + 'static,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: 'static + MessageBody,
{
    type Response = ServiceResponse<EitherBody<B, BoxBody>>;
    type Error = Error;
    type Transform = RateLimiterMiddleware<S>;
    type InitError = ();
    type Future = Ready<Result<Self::Transform, Self::InitError>>;

    fn new_transform(&self, service: S) -> Self::Future {
        ok(RateLimiterMiddleware {
            service: Arc::new(service),
            limiter: self.limiter.clone(),
        })
    }
}

impl<S, B> Service<ServiceRequest> for RateLimiterMiddleware<S>
where
    S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response=ServiceResponse<B>, Error=Error> + 'static,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: 'static + MessageBody,
{
    type Response = ServiceResponse<EitherBody<B, BoxBody>>;
    type Error = Error;
    type Future = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=Result<Self::Response, Self::Error>>>>;

    fn poll_ready(&self, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Result<(), Self::Error>> {
        self.service.poll_ready(cx)
    }

    fn call(&self, req: ServiceRequest) -> Self::Future {
        let limiter = Arc::clone(&self.limiter);
        let service = Arc::clone(&self.service);

        Box::pin(handle_rate_limiting(req, limiter, service))
    }
}

pub async fn handle_rate_limiting<S, B>(
    req: ServiceRequest,
    limiter: Arc<Mutex<Limiter>>,
    service: Arc<S>,
) -> Result<ServiceResponse<EitherBody<B>>, Error>
where
    S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response=ServiceResponse<B>, Error=Error>,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: 'static + MessageBody,
{
    let ip = match req.peer_addr() {
        Some(addr) => addr.ip().to_string(),
        None => {
            let bad_request_response = HttpResponse::BadRequest()
                .content_type("text/html")
                .body("Missing IP address.");
            return Ok(ServiceResponse::new(req.request().clone(), bad_request_response)
                .map_into_boxed_body()
                .map_into_right_body());
        }
    };
    let now = Utc::now();

    let (last_request_time, request_count) = {
        let mut limiter = limiter.lock().unwrap();
        limiter.ip_addresses.entry(ip.clone()).or_insert((now, 0)).clone()
    };

    println!("IP: {} - Last Request Time: {}, Request Count: {}", ip, last_request_time, request_count);

    let mut too_many_requests = false;
    let mut new_last_request_time = last_request_time;
    let mut new_request_count = request_count;

    let limiter_duration_secs = limiter.lock().unwrap().duration.num_seconds();

    if now - last_request_time <= Duration::seconds(limiter_duration_secs) {
        if request_count >= limiter.lock().unwrap().num_requests {
            too_many_requests = true;
        } else {
            new_request_count += 1;
            println!("IP: {} - Incremented Request Count: {}", ip, new_request_count);
        }
    } else {
        // Reset time and count
        new_last_request_time = now;
        new_request_count = 1;
        println!("IP: {} - Reset Request Count and Time", ip);
    }

    {
        let mut limiter = limiter.lock().unwrap();
        let entry = limiter.ip_addresses.entry(ip.clone()).or_insert((now, 0));
        entry.0 = new_last_request_time;
        entry.1 = new_request_count;
    }

    if too_many_requests {
        println!("IP: {} - Too Many Requests", ip);
        let message = format!("Too many requests. Please try again in {} seconds.", limiter_duration_secs.to_string());

        let too_many_requests_response = HttpResponse::TooManyRequests()
            .content_type("text/html")
            .insert_header(("Retry-After", limiter_duration_secs.to_string()))
            .body(message);
        return Ok(ServiceResponse::new(req.request().clone(), too_many_requests_response)
            .map_into_boxed_body()
            .map_into_right_body());
    }

    let res: ServiceResponse<B> = service.call(req).await?;
    Ok(res.map_into_left_body())
}


It can be used as shown below:
use rate_limit::{LimiterBuilder, RateLimiter};

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .app_data(web::Data::new(app_state.clone()))
            .wrap(Logger::default())
            .wrap(RateLimiter::new(Arc::clone(&limiter)))
            .service(some_endpoint_function)
    })


I've written the following tests:
use actix_web::{
    http::StatusCode,
    test::{call_service, init_service, TestRequest},
    web, App, HttpResponse,
};
use std::sync::Arc;
use rate_limit::{LimiterBuilder, RateLimiter};
use actix_rt::time::sleep;
use std::time::Duration as StdDuration;
use std::net::{IpAddr, Ipv4Addr, SocketAddr};
use chrono::Duration;

#[actix_rt::test]
async fn test_rate_limiter_allows_two_requests() {
    let limiter = LimiterBuilder::new()
        .with_duration(Duration::seconds(20))
        .with_num_requests(2)
        .build();

    let service = init_service(
        App::new()
            .wrap(RateLimiter::new(Arc::clone(&limiter)))
            .route("/", web::get().to(HttpResponse::Ok)),
    )
        .await;

    // Simulate two requests from the same IP within 20 seconds
    let req = TestRequest::default()
        .peer_addr(SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 1)), 12345))
        .to_request();
    let resp = call_service(&service, req).await;
    assert_eq!(resp.status(), StatusCode::OK);

    let req = TestRequest::default()
        .peer_addr(SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 1)), 12345))
        .to_request();
    let resp = call_service(&service, req).await;
    assert_eq!(resp.status(), StatusCode::OK);

    // Third request within 20 seconds should be rate-limited
    let req = TestRequest::default()
        .peer_addr(SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 1)), 12345))
        .to_request();
    let resp = call_service(&service, req).await;
    assert_eq!(resp.status(), StatusCode::TOO_MANY_REQUESTS);

    // Attempt a fourth request immediately (Expected to fail also)
    let req = TestRequest::default()
        .peer_addr(SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 1)), 12345))
        .to_request();
    let resp = call_service(&service, req).await;
    assert_eq!(resp.status(), StatusCode::TOO_MANY_REQUESTS);
}

#[actix_rt::test]
async fn test_rate_limiter_allows_after_duration() {
    let limiter = LimiterBuilder::new()
        .with_duration(Duration::seconds(20))
        .with_num_requests(2)
        .build();

    let service = init_service(
        App::new()
            .wrap(RateLimiter::new(Arc::clone(&limiter)))
            .route("/", web::get().to(HttpResponse::Ok)),
    )
        .await;

    // First request should succeed
    let req = TestRequest::default()
        .peer_addr(SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 1)), 12345))
        .to_request();
    let resp = call_service(&service, req).await;
    assert_eq!(resp.status(), StatusCode::OK);

    // Second request should succeed
    let req = TestRequest::default()
        .peer_addr(SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 1)), 12345))
        .to_request();
    let resp = call_service(&service, req).await;
    assert_eq!(resp.status(), StatusCode::OK);

    // Wait for more than 20 seconds
    sleep(StdDuration::from_secs(21)).await;

    // Third request should also succeed after waiting
    let req = TestRequest::default()
        .peer_addr(SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 1)), 12345))
        .to_request();
    let resp = call_service(&service, req).await;
    assert_eq!(resp.status(), StatusCode::OK);

    // Fourth request after waiting should succeed
    let req = TestRequest::default()
        .peer_addr(SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 1)), 12345))
        .to_request();
    let resp = call_service(&service, req).await;
    assert_eq!(resp.status(), StatusCode::OK);
}

#[actix_rt::test]
async fn test_rate_limiter_with_different_ips() {
    let limiter = LimiterBuilder::new()
        .with_duration(Duration::seconds(20))
        .with_num_requests(2)
        .build();

    let service = init_service(
        App::new()
            .wrap(RateLimiter::new(Arc::clone(&limiter)))
            .route("/", web::get().to(HttpResponse::Ok)),
    )
        .await;

    // First request from IP 127.0.0.1
    let req = TestRequest::default()
        .peer_addr(SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 1)), 12345))
        .to_request();
    let resp = call_service(&service, req).await;
    assert_eq!(resp.status(), StatusCode::OK);

    // First request from IP 127.0.0.2
    let req = TestRequest::default()
        .peer_addr(SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 2)), 12345))
        .to_request();
    let resp = call_service(&service, req).await;
    assert_eq!(resp.status(), StatusCode::OK);

    // Second request from IP 127.0.0.1
    let req = TestRequest::default()
        .peer_addr(SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 1)), 12345))
        .to_request();
    let resp = call_service(&service, req).await;
    assert_eq!(resp.status(), StatusCode::OK);

    // Third request from IP 127.0.0.1 within 20 seconds should be rate-limited
    let req = TestRequest::default()
        .peer_addr(SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 1)), 12345))
        .to_request();
    let resp = call_service(&service, req).await;
    assert_eq!(resp.status(), StatusCode::TOO_MANY_REQUESTS);
}

#[actix_rt::test]
async fn test_rate_limiter_handles_missing_ip() {
    let limiter = LimiterBuilder::new()
        .with_duration(Duration::seconds(20))
        .with_num_requests(2)
        .build();

    let service = init_service(
        App::new()
            .wrap(RateLimiter::new(Arc::clone(&limiter)))
            .route("/", web::get().to(HttpResponse::Ok)),
    )
        .await;

    // Simulate a request without an IP address
    let req = TestRequest::default().to_request();
    let resp = call_service(&service, req).await;
    assert_eq!(resp.status(), StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST);
}


I would like to know if there is anything wrong before I publish it - even minor improvements that could make it more idiomatic.

pub struct Limiter {
    pub ip_addresses: HashMap<String, (DateTime<Utc>, usize)>,
    pub duration: Duration,
    pub num_requests: usize,
}

Don't convert the SocketAddr to String for the keys, just use SocketAddr as the key. I'd also use a struct instead of the tuple for the value. That would just make the code a lot clearer.
let ip = match req.peer_addr() {
    Some(addr) => addr.ip().to_string(),
    None => {
        let bad_request_response = HttpResponse::BadRequest()
            .content_type("text/html")
            .body("Missing IP address.");
        return Ok(ServiceResponse::new(req.request().clone(), bad_request_response)
            .map_into_boxed_body()
            .map_into_right_body());
    }
};

The documentation for peer_addr indicates that it only returns None when run under a unit test. In light of that, I wouldn't have this error handling for it. I'd either disable the rate limiting when it it returns None, or I'd just panic.
 let mut limiter = limiter.lock().unwrap();

You lock and unlock the mutex multiple times in a very short span of code, which seems like its going to be bad for performance. I'd design the code to lock the mutex once, do all the logic I need, and then unlock it.
    println!("IP: {} - Too Many Requests", ip);

If I installed a crate, and found it had println! statements in it, I'd immediately uninstall that crate and never look at it again.
    let message = format!("Too many requests. Please try again in {} seconds.", limiter_duration_secs.to_string());

    let too_many_requests_response = HttpResponse::TooManyRequests()
        .content_type("text/html")
        .insert_header(("Retry-After", limiter_duration_secs.to_string()))
        .body(message);

Your content type claims this is html, but it is really plain text.

Thank you for taking the time to provide such a thorough review. How would you handle the program output? Some users of the crate may like to see request information as part of the server logs. Would you instead use a dedicated log library?

@JohnHarrington, the standard approach here is the log crate. Your library sends logs to that crate, and the person using your crate can plug into and do whatever they like with the logs.

Some nits:

LimiterBuilder::new() should accept all attributes of the struct as parameters and forward those to the constructor. Your current implementation of new() should be implemented as Default::default.
The call to to_string() in format!("Too many requests. Please try again in {} seconds.", limiter_duration_secs.to_string()); is redundant: format!("Too many requests. Please try again in {} seconds.", limiter_duration_secs); or format!("Too many requests. Please try again in {limiter_duration_secs} seconds.");

